# Authorization Header of HttpClient Not Being Passed

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I've looked at multiple posts about this and none of the solutions that I see seem to work in my case.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _Endpoint);
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("APIToken", _apiKey);
//request.Headers.Add("Authorization APIToken", _apiKey);
request.Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(contacts))
{
    Headers =
    {
        ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
    }
};

using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request))
{
    var readstring = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    ...
}
```

The `request.Headers.Add` is commented out because I tried to do it that way initially.

I also set `DefaultRequestHeader` when creating `_client`:

```
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("APIToken", _apiKey);
```

It runs in Postman with the header parameter set as:

```
Authorization: APIToken [APIKey]
```

When I set a breakpoint just before calling SendAsync I can see that the correct values are loaded for the Authorization headed.

[image]

But I get the error message from the server that says:

> "Authentication credentials were not provided."

There's a different message returned if I enter the wrong APIKey in Postman which tells me that it's not sending incorrect credentials, it isn't sending the authorization header at all.

Comment: What happens if you try `request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "APIToken " +_apiKey);` Side note: don't use `.Result`, use `await`.

Comment: I still get "Authentication credentials were not provided" when I use that

Comment: Did you check that you have the "Bearer" in the authorization with your token?

Answer (score 0):

It was being redirected and the authorization token was not being passed during the redirect. I had to point to the final url in order to get it to work.